# \n in NSSting * and .plist

Tags: iphone, encoding

Code:

```
NSString *strDirect = @"Dummy\nMessage";
NSString *strBundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"MessageDummy"];
NSLog(@"Direct: %@", strDirect);
NSLog(@"Bundle: %@", strBundle);
```

where `MessageDummy` is a string type value `Dummy\nMessage` in the .plist file. i.e.:

```
  <key>MessageDummy</key>
  <string>Dummy\nMessage</string>
```

Output:

```
2010-08-09 11:49:18.641 Plan[15558:207] Direct: Dummy
Message
2010-08-09 11:49:18.642 Plan[15558:207] Bundle: Dummy\nMessage
```

`\n` is honored in `NSString *` but not when returned from `objectForKey`. How can I make the return value of `objectForKey` behaves same as the `NSString *`?

Comment: What does the .plist look like? Does it have \n or a linebreak?

Comment: I updated the question with `MessageDummy` key and value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while "\n" is treated as "\\n" while you are trying to retrieve it (\ is escaped with \\). The work around for this is, instead of using

```
<key>MessageDummy</key>
<string>Dummy\nMessage</string>
```

use:

```
<key>MessageDummy</key>
  <string>Dummy
          Message</string>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Madhup's answer, its probably worth pointing out that "\n" is a C-compiler construct, a mechanism for communicating a desire to include a newline in a literal string defined in source code.

Plists are stored in XML format which has its own data format, escaping rules, etc.

There is no relationship between the two, and you should not expect similiar behaviour between the two.